# Drupal - Displaying page / form variables for node add/edit and comments

Tags: drupal

How can I print the variables of Drupal's node add/edit and comment forms?

I've tried `print_r($form);` It returns `NULL`.

Here's my module:

```
function comment_mod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, array('comment_form'))) {
        unset($form['homepage']); // this works
    print_r($form);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you implementing the [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) function in your module? This will be called for all forms, so if you add your calls and visit the node add/edit page you should see some output. From what you've said I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: The code example looks fine to me and worked when i tried it. Are you putting that code directly in the .module file? or in an include file?

Comment: Yep, in a comment_mod.module file. Getting nothing